# How do I make the aside have the width of the remaining area?

Tags: css

I have a simple page with content on the left and an `aside` on the right. I would like the `div` on the left to be 70% of the width of the container and then the `aside` take up the rest of the space, but I can't figure out how to give it a variable width.

I've tried setting the width of the `aside` to be 30%, but that doesn't leave any room for the 24px of space I'd like between the `div` and the `aside`. I also tried setting the width of the aside to be 28% and that gets it close, but I figured there's a more precise way of doing it.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 24px;
}
.left {
  background-color: white;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  background-color: white;
  width: 28%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <aside class="right"></aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into Sass, you can use the CSS `calc();` function.

Note that in the CSS below, I'm keeping your 28% value for graceful degradation on older browsers that do not support `calc()` *(Old Android browsers, Opera Mini and IE8-)*.

Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/orvn/dyvhsmvu/).

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 24px;
}
.left {
  background-color: white;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  background-color: white;
  width: 28%;
  width: calc(30% - 24px);
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Works great! I wasn't sure if I'd be able to do this a "cleaner" way or not, but this works well and has pretty solid browser support. Thanks!

Comment: More dynamic CSS like this (without the use of pre/post-processors) is the future. Excited about CSS4 variables being adopted by browsers soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, how about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9fy6txpa/

```
.left {
  background-color: white;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-right:24px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Set the widths to 70% and 30% as desired.  Instead of having a margin/padding between the div and the aside, give the div a 24px wide right-border and then change it's `box-sizing` property to `border-box`.  That way, it's width will be 70% *including* the added border (a total width of 70%, not 70% plus the border as the default box model does).

Comment: I like the creativity of this one, but it leaves a super small white line at the top and the bottom of the space between the two white boxes.

Comment: @nicholas79171 I can't see it in Chrome.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well, but on a 4K monitor, that might make a difference. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NmjyMhp.png) where I set the height of the aside to 50% so you can see it more clearly.

Comment: I've solved something like this before on retina displays using `zoom:1;` and `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`